# What kind of lawyer should I speak with about getting out of a lease on the basis of breach of contract?

Tags: residential-lease, breaking-the-lease

The apartment complex I’m renting from are shirking their obligations to me by blaming the issues on me.  Can I get out of these lease without paying the fee for early lease breaking?

Comment: Adding a jurisdiction to this question and being specific about the things that the landlord isn't doing will increase the chances that you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want a lawyer who accepts tenant-side landlord tenant cases, usually a solo practitioner or small law firm or legal clinic. Medium to large sized law firms usually don't practice that kind of law at all, or only represent landlords, as a matter of policy.

The usual problem, however, is that lawyers are often too expensive relative to the amount in controversy to make sense to hire to fully represent you in a matter like this one. You might want to have a "limited engagement" such as a one time consult with a lawyer, rather than a full retention of a lawyer, over an issue like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains no details as to jurisdiction, the nature of the "obligations" the complex is "shirking", what arguments the complex has that you are responsible, or what argument and evidence you have to support your claim. Most jurisdictions do impose minimal habitability requirements on residential leases. You would have to consult local laws to see what they are and determine whether your complex is failing to satisfy them. If they are, you can file a claim of [constructive eviction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_eviction). However, if the complex disputes your claim, you may have to defend your claim in court, which will likely involve legal expenses, and you will have to provide evidence. So you should be documenting whatever it is you think the complex is doing wrong.